# Replaced battery won't charge (macbook pro 2015 model)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My MBP battery got swollen and replaced it with the new one. Everything is connected properly, battery is detected but it doesn't hold the charge (laptop shuts down immediately after unplugging the cable) and doesn't charge at all.

I have tried SMC reset few times but it didn't work.

This is the battery report from coconutBattery:

[image]

Cable works fine. I can turn on the laptop while plugged, it's the battery that won't charge.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Who replaced the battery?  Apple?

Comment: I've replaced it myself. But I've done it properly. I suspect the battery isn't functional and I can't even return it. But I still hope there might be something concerning internal circuitry that might be easily tweaked or repaired.